# How to make a section heading indented using value of parindent?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, indentation, titlesec

While trying to use the `titlesec` package to format subsection headings, I have run into some trouble.  I need subsection headings formatted so that they are indented using the value that is set with the command `\setlength{\parindent}{[some length]}`, where `[some length]` is an arbitrary length.

More specifically, I would like to use something similar to this:

```
...
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[.]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0em}{0ex}{1em}
...
\subsection{[subsection title]} Subsection text ...
```

in order to produce subsection headings that look like this:

```
[parindent-length space][subsection title]. Subsection text that is
not indented just like you would expect in a regular paragraph
```

Answer (score 3):

The following MWE will show how to indent `\subsection` content by `\parindent`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\itshape}{\thesubsection.}{3pt}{\space}[.]
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{\parindent}{1ex}{1em}

\setlength{\parindent}{4pc} % exaggerated for the example

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection Title} 
Subsection text goes here.
Subsection text goes here.
Subsection text goes here.
Subsection text goes here.
Subsection text goes here.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

You can see that the second argument of `\titlespacing*` is set to `\parindent`.

[image]

Without the setting of `\parindent` (which in the above code was just to emphasize the indentation), you get

[image]