# Hierarchy and numbering of sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Desired Section Hierarchy]

But this is the closest I came so far:

[image: Achieved so far]

Here goes my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}.} {\leftskip=2cm}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\roman{subsubsection}.} {\leftskip=3cm}

\begin{document}

\section{Situational Analysis}
\subsection{Company}
\subsubsection{Mission Statement}


\end{document}
```

The `\leftskip=Xcm` doesn't do any good. 
Is there any simple solution? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: After a quick search this former [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153846/indent-every-subsubsection-element) came up.

Comment: After a quick check I found this was not what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319016/how-to-make-a-section-heading-indented-using-value-of-parindent)

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{4em}{1ex}{1em}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{8em}{1ex}{1em}
```

does the trick. The first measure is the indentation, adjust as required.

The other two measures are vertical spacing above and below the (sub)(sub)section title, respectively. Not sure how to get their default values, though. You might want to adjust them according to your document class.

Comment: Didn't notice this earlier. Thanks a lot as well. I'm going for this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can renew the environments as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}.} 
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\roman{subsubsection}.} 


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\leftskip 25pt\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\leftskip 50pt\@startsection{subsubsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  

\section{My section}

Here is a section.

\subsection{My subsection}

Here is a subsection.

\subsubsection{My subsubsection}

Here is a subsubsection.

\end{document}
```

This code will also indent the text after a section, subsection, etc...

[image]

Hope it helps.

Romain